# How do I loop through multiple folders and append files?

Tags: python, json, directory

I downloaded my Facebook messenger data and it came in a series of folders with a JSON file in each. I want to write a script that will go through each folder and append all the JSONs together.

Example: there are 10 folders in '/home/Desktop/messages/inbox' named `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']`.

There is one JSON file in each folder

`[message_a.json, message_b.json, message_c.json, message_d.json, message_e.json, message_f.json, message_g.json. message_h.json, message_i.json, message_j.json]`

Thanks!

and a JSON file in each folder

Comment: Can you show the json format in each file?

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
import json
import glob

directory = '/home/Desktop/messages/inbox'
outfile = '/home/Desktop/messages/inbox/merged_json.json'


result = []
for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    for f in glob.glob(directory + "/" + folder + "*/.json"):
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            result.append(json.load(infile))

with open(outfile, "wb") as out:
     json.dump(result, out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
folders = os.listdir('inbox/')

for i in range(len(folders)):
    folder = folders[i]
    with open(f'inbox/{folder}/message_1.json', 'r') as f:
        result.append(json.load(f))
```

Thanks for the answers, this is what I ended up using!